# How to suppress "DLL not found" popup in cygwin?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, dll, cygwin

I have written a bash script running in a Windows Cygwin environment that pulls our current sources from a GitLab server, compiles it, and runs the unit tests. Problem is: If something's wrong with the sources and the unit test cannot find all of its DLLs, Windows shows a popup window complaining about the missing DLL, which blocks my bash script from continuing.

Is it possible to tell Cygwin/Windows *not* to show that message box? Or, alternatively, is there a way how I could check in advance if the .exe is going to find all of its DLLs? (Of course, I cannot simply check against a fixed list of DLLs, since that could change any time when changes are made to the sources.)

Answer (score 2):

You can list the DLLs used by `a.exe` using either the `ldd a.exe` and `cygcheck a.exe` commands. Success looks like:

```
$ ldd bin/triad.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ff8c1590000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ff8c00f0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ff8bf080000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x7ff8717d0000)


$ cygcheck bin/triad.exe
C:\cygwin64\home\Doug\bin\triad.exe
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

Failure looks like:

```
> ldd triad.exe
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ff8c1590000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ff8c00f0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ff8bf080000)
        cygwin1.dll => not found

> cygcheck .\triad.exe
C:\cygwin64\home\Doug\bin\triad.exe
cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygwin1.dll

  C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

Comment: This looks promising, but for some reason, neither `ldd` nor `cygcheck` say anything about that particular dll that's currently missing.

Comment: That suggests that the missing DLL is dynamically loaded. What is the name of the missing DLL reported in the dialog? Is this DLL actually present on your machine. On windows, all DLLs must be in the same folder as the .EXE, or in one of the folders in the PATH variable. (Windows and cygwin have distinct PATH variables.) HTH.

Comment: The DLL is MSVCR100.DLL, which is the C++ runtime and usually resides in the Windows directory, not in the folder of the EXE.

Comment: On my system:`dir c:\Windows\system32\msvcr100.dll` ->`2011-06-11  03:15           829,264 msvcr100.dll`

Answer (score 1):

See the [`SetErrorMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode) function.

> `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 0x0001`
>
> The system does not display the critical-error-handler message box. Instead, the system sends the error to the calling process.
>
> Best practice is that all applications call the process-wide SetErrorMode function with a parameter of SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup. This is to prevent error mode dialogs from hanging the application.

Rather critically

> A child process inherits the error mode of its parent process

making it possible for your test harness to control the behavior of the process it's trying to test.

Also pay attention to the correct way to set one flag without disturbing others: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040727-00/?p=38323

Comment: And yes, this is likely a pain to do from shell script.  You may need a shim executable to launch the unit under test, either a single-purpose launcher ala `nice`/`nohup`/etc, or a more capable scripting engine that can make WinApi calls.

Answer (score 0):

We actually do what you think is a bad idea: We have a list of files (or packages) that are expected in the build output and the build fails before the unit test step if this requirement is not met. Since any new file (or an old file gone) requires an update to the installer most of the time, this isn't so big of a deal. And then it's still relatively rare that new dlls are added to the project.

There are tools to check the references of dlls (I'm assuming you're using C++ here?), such as dependency viewer. [The new version](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) of this one is even open-source, but I have never used this in a command line environment.